# Classification issues between Rvest and Map_dfr during web-scrape

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest, magrittr

I'm currently scraping stats from a website, but on certain stat pages I hit a snag with the following prompt:

Error: Column `avg` can't be converted from numeric to character

I try something like mutate(avg = avg %>% as.numeric), but then I get the prompt the column avg can't be found.

The issue in the code below occurs whenever I add stat_id 336 or 340. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)


df <- expand.grid(
  tournament_id = c("t464", "t054", "t047"),
  stat_id = c("02564", "101", "102", "336", "340")
) %>% 
  mutate(
    links = paste0(
      'https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.',
      stat_id,
      '.y2019.eon.',
      tournament_id,
      '.html'
    )
  ) %>% 
  as_tibble()

# Function to get the table
get_info <- function(link, tournament) {
  link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table() %>%
    .[[2]] %>%
    clean_names() %>% 
    select(-rank_last_week ) %>% 
    mutate(rank_this_week = rank_this_week %>% 
             as.character) %>%
    mutate(tournament) 
}

# Retrieve the tables and bind them
test12 <- df %$%
  map2_dfr(links, tournament_id, get_info) 
test12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't want to put a pipe inside of a dplyr verb, or at least I have never before seen that done. Not sure why you need that in this example as average automatically parses as numeric. Try this instead:

```r
# Function to get the table
get_info <- function(link, tournament_id) {
  data <- link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table() %>%
    .[[2]] %>%
    clean_names() %>% 
    select(-rank_last_week ) %>% 
    mutate(rank_this_week = as.integer(str_extract(rank_this_week, "\\d+")))
  try(data <- mutate(data, avg = as.character(avg)), silent = TRUE)
  try(data <- mutate(data, total_distance_feet = as.character(total_distance_feet)), silent = TRUE)
  data
}

test12 <- df %>%
  mutate(tables = map2(links, tournament_id, get_info)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(everything())
```

Comment: Thanks @dcsuka - I really appreciate you helping clean up my code. Also, can I get a little more guidance. On the code you provided I get 4 columns: tournament_id, stat_id, links, tables. Under the tables column, it says 7 variables. Is there a way to turn this into one dataframe or tibble where all the info is on one spot? Basically, where all the variables will show up on the one dataframe.

Comment: Sure, I made the edits required. You may have to do some string manipulation on some of the variables if you want to turn them back to integer.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for all of your help. Cool to see some new formulas. I had not seen the try(), silent = TRUE, or unnest.

Comment: Glad you learned something!

Comment: also, converting the variables back to integers was seamless. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm running into issues with this code when I add more variables to my stat_id and tournament_id. I get the error message below which should be independent of the added variables. Are there any troubleshoots to get around this?

Error: Can't combine `..1$tables$player_name` <character> and `..2$tables$player_name` <logical>.

 tournament_id = c("t464", "t521", "t054", "t047", "t493", "t016", "t006", "t002", "t004", "t003", "t005", "t007", "t473", "t010", "t009", "t011", "t475", "t041", "t012", "t480", "t019", "t033", "t021", "t023", "t032", "t026", "t034", "t524", "t525", "t030", "t518")

Comment: This should be asked as a new question, with full code to reproduce the issue. Feel free to link the new post here, and I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks @dcsuka - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74390349/how-to-bypass-empty-tables-in-web-scrape-in-r